# 'I will GO to (verb)' vs. 'I will (verb)'

Tags: verbs, particle-に

In sentences like

> ２時ごろ子どもを迎えに行きます。I will **go** to meet/greet my child around 2 O'clock.

Is the sentence structure of verb(Stem form)に行く/来る/帰る, ever strictly necessary? Or following the example, would

> ２時ごろ子どもを迎えます。I will meet/greet my child around 2 O'clock.

be sufficient. In other words, is the fact that you will go somewhere to do this action already implied (in some cases).

Another example:

> 来月旅行に行きます。I will **go** travel next month. VS. 来月旅行します。I will travel next month.

Aside: I can see how in examples like

> 映画を見に行きたいです。I want to **go** see a film.

The format it's written in would be useful, as the emphasis is placed on the fact that you wish to go somewhere to see a film, not simply that you want to watch a film.

Thank you for, any and all, help! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ２時ごろ子どもを迎えに行きます。
>   ２時ごろ子どもを迎えます。

These are very different.

- ２時ごろ子どもを迎えに行きます。 I will pick the children up around two o'clock.
- ２時ごろ子どもを迎えます。 I welcome the children (to the place) around two o'clock.

In this case, 迎える and 迎えに行く are different. However,

- 映画を見ます I watch a movie.
- 映画を見に行きます I go and watch a movie.

These ones are not too much, one is just saying 'watch movie at anywhere', you can watch movies at home these days.  Another is saying 'watch a movie in a certain place', likewise a theatre. The latter one implies, you are going out of your home and watch a movie.

来月、旅行に行きます is a formal expression. And 来月、旅行します sounds a casual expression. In this case, 旅行に行く is a very popular and common phrase/term for travel almost an idiom/colloquial thing thus 旅行する sounds ill-mannered or unnatural.